# Data Migration using Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am migrating a java application already written to Spring batch. This application will do data migration across 2 different environment. The application is designed as below

1) To read a set of user id from source DB based on some flag.

2) read the user specific data from 3 different database in the source environment for each user.

3) write the data in the destination database for each user.

I also need to implement parallel processing, so that at a time 10 or more threads will run and each thread will be responsible for migration of a individual user’s data.

I am completely new to spring and so having problem to visualizing the structure of my configuration xml. I am thinking of having a step to read the set of user Id first and then pass it to the second step, which will be responsible for reading user specific data, and writing it. But I am having problems while implementing the same. It will really help me if someone can suggest me a structure of the same in the context of spring batch, with parallel processing

Comment: It aren't steps. I would create a single step with a reader, processor and writer. 1. would be the reader, 2. would be an ItemProcessor, 3. would be the writer. So don't think steps, think chunks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect this to be a single step job:

```
<job>
    <step id="step1">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="flagReader" processor="userSpecificDataProcessor" writer="databaseWriter" commit-count="10"/>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>
```

The flagReader would read in the user ids based on the flag, the processor would look up the extra data by id and build the appropriate object populated with that data.  The writer would write the resulting object to the database.

With regards to the requirement to parallelize, take a look at partitioned steps.  I'd start with the basics first though and address parallelizing them later (it's easy to add once you have the basic job running).